# How to concatenate two IEnumerable's and project them into a grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

I have two `IEnumerable<StatusGroup>` where `StatusGroup` like

```
public class StatusGroup
    {
        public DateTime ExamDate{ get; set; }
        public int SuccessCount{ get; set; }
        public int FailCount{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to merge the two IEnumerable, so the result will have just one record for each date and the sum of counters properties should be calculated

for example

```
List1={Date= 01/01/2016 , Success=10, Fail=0}
List2={Date= 01/01/2016 , Success=0, Fail=3}
```

the result should be

```
List2={Date= 01/01/2016 , Success=10, Fail=3}
```

Comment: GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => new StatusGroup { Date = x.Key, Success = x.Sum(y => y.Success) ... })

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: Can the individual lists have duplicate dates within them, or is each date unique within each individual list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do Concat/Union, and then group by Date. Code will look approximately like this:

```
var list3 = List1.Concat(List2)
                             .GroupBy(x => x.Date)  
                             .Select(grouping => 
                                 new StatusGroup
                                 {
                                     Date = grouping.Key, 
                                     SuccessCount = grouping.Sum(x => x.SuccessCount), 
                                     FailCount = grouping.Sum(x => x.FailCount)
                                 });
```

Comment: Don't use `Union`. `Union` removes duplicates, which gives you the wrong sum. Use `Concat`.

Comment: @hvd For structs, yes, but not classes - Unless they've overridden the `Equals` method, of course (and a duplicate class in *this* case seems wrong to me). Though your point is still valid.

Comment: @Rob Depends in the class. If it overrides `Equals` and `GetHashcode` or not.

Comment: @Magnus Just edited that into my comment for clarification as you posted :)

Comment: You might also want to use `.GroupBy(x => x.ExamDate.Date)` to ignore the time portion. It sounds as if OP wants one object for every date(not `DateTime`).

Comment: @Rob Still the intention when using `Union` is to remove duplicates whether it actually does it or not. So if the intention is to keep duplicates `union` should not be used.

Comment: Thank you, I edited a post to use Concat, though I was not sure about content of these 2 lists used in original post, so if they would have "duplicates" added to both lists for some reason, and they would have to be removed from target list.

Comment: @raderick If the same item is in both lists *they should be grouped together and their values summed*; that's exactly what the specs say.